# Change quantity of product in django ecommerce website? DJANGO

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates, javascript-objects

It's not giving an error. The quantity is being changed only in the first product, even if when I press arrow of second product, the quantity of first product is being changed.
**cart.js**

```
var changeQ = document.getElementsByClassName('increase')


for (i = 0; i < changeQ.length; i++) {
    changeQ[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
        
        
        if (action == 'plus'){
            Increase(productId, action)
        }
        else if(action=='minus'){
            Decrease(productId, action)
        }
    })
}

function Increase(productId,action){
    console.log('Increase')
    var quantity = Number(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
    quantity = quantity+1;
    document.getElementById("quantity").value = quantity;
    console.log(quantity);
}

function Decrease(productId,action){
    var quantity = Number(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
    console.log('Decrease')
    quantity = quantity-1;
    document.getElementById("quantity").value=quantity;

}
```

**template**

```
<div class="counter">
    <div class="arrow-up increase" id="arrow-up" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="plus" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
    <div class="quantity"><input type="number" id="quantity" value="1"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down increase" id="arrow-down" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="minus"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
  
  </div>
```

It's in Django. So what can I do to indicate the specific product. Can someone help me to solve this problem, please!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) in the `Increase` and `Decrease` functions it returns the first element with `id='quantity'` which is why you are only able to set the quantity for the first product.

So you need to use some value to distinguish between the `input` tags with `id='quantity'`. I would suggest adding `data-product="{{ item.product.id }}"` to the `input` tag since you are already passing the product id as `productId` to both the functions.

Thus your template would be some thing like this

```
<div class="counter">
    <div class="arrow-up increase" id="arrow-up" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="plus" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
    <div class="quantity"><input type="number" id="quantity" value="1" data-product="{{item.product.id}}"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down increase" id="arrow-down" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="minus"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
</div>
```

And the `Increase` and `Decrease` functions would be modified like so

```
function Increase(productId,action){
    console.log('Increase')
    var quantity = Number(document.querySelector(`input[data-product=${productId}]`).value);
    quantity = quantity+1;
    document.querySelector(`input[data-product=${productId}]`).value = quantity;
    console.log(quantity);
}

function Decrease(productId,action){
    var quantity = Number(document.querySelector(`input[data-product=${productId}]`).value);
    console.log('Decrease')
    quantity = quantity-1;
    document.querySelector(`input[data-product=${productId}]`).value=quantity;
}
```

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) allows us to use CSS selectors to select elements. Here we use it to select `input` tags with the `data-product` attribute equal to the value in `productId`.
- [`${}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is for string interpolation, we can use it to insert the `productId` into the selector string.

Comment: @BehzodUrinov Could you please specify what exactly you want me to explain further. You should be able to copy the code I've written and run it. But let me know what you want me to clarify.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[data-product=]' is not a valid selector.
    at Increase (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/cart.js:23:36)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/cart.js:13:13)
Increase @ cart.js:23
(anonymous) @ cart.js:13

Comment: I am having this issue. I think all things are fine, but giving error?

Comment: @BehzodUrinov The error says `document.querySelector()` is using the selector `input[data-product=]`, it is missing the value from `productId` . So check the function added as the event handler in `changeQ[i].addEventListener()` and ensure that when you call the `Increase` or `Decrease` function from the event handler that the `productId` is being passed.

It might also be helpful if you you `console.log(productId)` in the `Increase` and `Decrease` functions to check the value of `productId`.